# While using npm exceljs in nodejs and generating excel it's not opening in Microsoft excel 2007

Tags: node.js, excel, npm, mean-stack, exceljs

I have used exceljs npm in Nodejs application to generate the excel file of my preformatted data.

It is working as expected and downloading the excel file. The file is opening in all software except the MS Excel 2007. It is showing the error as below image and if we press yes, just opening the new sheet. The error is in below screenshot

[image]

The code I used as below.

```
exports.getDocExcel = function(req, res) {


  var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

  var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Manage_Customer');

  worksheet.columns = [{
      header: 'SoldTo_Customer',
      key: 'SoldTo_Customer',
      width: 20
    },
    {
      header: 'CDC_CustomerID',
      key: 'CDC_CustomerID',
      width: 20
    },
    {
      header: 'CDC_Name',
      key: 'CDC_Name',
      width: 20
    },
    {
      header: 'CDC_City',
      key: 'CDC_City',
      width: 20
    },
    {
      header: 'CDC_State',
      key: 'CDC_State',
      width: 20
    },
    {
      header: 'CDC_Zip',
      key: 'CDC_Zip',
      width: 20
    },



  ];

  var fileName = "sample.xlsx";
  var tempFilePath = __dirname + fileName;

  workbook.xlsx.writeFile(tempFilePath).then(function() {
    fs.readFile(tempFilePath, function(err, data) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
      res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    });
  });

};
```

The server page as below

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const multipart = require("connect-multiparty");
var sql = require("mssql");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/public"));
dotenv.load({ path: '.env.Config' });
app.set('port', process.env.App_PORT || 3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('%s server running on port', chalk.green('✓'), app.get('port'));
    console.log('  Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
});
const pdfController = require('./public/controllers/pdf.js');
app.get("/doc-to-excel",pdfController.getDocExcel);
```

How to solve this issue?